# How to create an AMI excluding some volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I have an EC2 Instance of Linux. In that Instance another EBS volume /dev/sdh is attached. Now when I create an AMI from that instance with EC2 API Tools. It creates 2 snapshots. Now my question is, How can I create AMI of that instance with only 1 snapshot. I don't want the snapshot of my attached volume(/dev/sdh).

Answer (score 2):

Using the `ec2-create-image` command line tool, you can specify the following option to exclude an attached EBS volume from the resulting AMI:

```
ec2-create-image --block-device-mapping /dev/sdh=none [...]
```

Using the "Create Image (EBS AMI)" button on the AWS Console, simply click the red `[X Remove]` button next to the EBS volume before clicking `[Yes, Create]`.